# Some YARN worker node not join cluster , while I create spark cluster on Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a spark cluster on dataproc with 1 master and 6 worker node.
On GCP console I can see 6 VMs are running, but I only see 5 nodes on YARN Node Manager UI.

When I ssh into that machine, from the yarn-yarn-nodemanager log, I see, it keeps restarting and reconnecting to NodeManager.

How can I make this node rejoin cluster ?

update: my command

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${GCS_CLUSTER} \ 
--image pyspark-with-conda \ 
--bucket test-spark-data \ 
--zone asia-east1-b \ 
--master-boot-disk-size 500GB \ 
--master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \ 
--num-masters 1 \ 
--num-workers 2 \ 
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-8 \ 
--num-preemptible-workers 4 \ 
--preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size 500GB
```

---

Error message：

```
2018-08-22 08:25:24,801 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at test-spark-cluster-m/10.140.0.34:8031
2018-08-22 08:25:24,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Sending out 0 NM container statuses: []
2018-08-22 08:25:24,843 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Registering with RM using containers :[]
2018-08-22 08:25:24,978 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Unexpected error starting NodeStatusUpdater
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.test-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:897)
2018-08-22 08:25:24,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl failed in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apach
e.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.test-155104.internal,
 Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeM
anager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.test-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:897)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.pv
max-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:252)
        ... 6 more
2018-08-22 08:25:25,081 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recie
ved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.test-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeM
anager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.test-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:897)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.pv
max-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:252)
        ... 6 more
2018-08-22 08:25:25,084 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8042
2018-08-22 08:25:25,185 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 60144
2018-08-22 08:25:25,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 60144
2018-08-22 08:25:25,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2018-08-22 08:25:25,187 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2018-08-22 08:25:25,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8040
2018-08-22 08:25:25,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8040
2018-08-22 08:25:25,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Public cache exiting
2018-08-22 08:25:25,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2018-08-22 08:25:25,205 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2018-08-22 08:25:25,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
2018-08-22 08:25:25,206 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
2018-08-22 08:25:25,206 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2018-08-22 08:25:25,206 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeM
anager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.test-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:897)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  test-spark-cluster-sw-kbvq.c.pv
max-155104.internal, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:252)
        ... 6 more
2018-08-22 08:25:25,208 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
```

Comment: I have try 5 times (delete and recreate whole cluster), finally all node join cluster.... QQ

Comment: What command are you using to create cluster?

Comment: gcloud dataproc clusters create ${GCS_CLUSTER} \
       --image pyspark-with-conda \
       --bucket  test-spark-data \
       --zone  asia-east1-b  \
       --master-boot-disk-size  500GB \
       --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
       --num-masters  1 \
       --num-workers  2 \
       --worker-machine-type n1-standard-8 \
       --num-preemptible-workers 4 \
       --preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size 500GB

Comment: Do you have any customization in your `pyspark-with-conda` image that restarts Dataproc Agent service? Do you use connectors init action?

Comment: My custom image only install some python package ：

    gsutil -m cp -r gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/bootstrap-conda.sh .
    gsutil -m cp -r gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/install-conda-env.sh .
    chmod 755 ./*conda*.sh

    # Install Miniconda / conda
    ./bootstrap-conda.sh

    # Update conda root environment with specific packages in pip and conda
    CONDA_PACKAGES='numpy pyspark requests scipy tzlocal'
    CONDA_PACKAGES=$CONDA_PACKAGES   PIP_PACKAGES=$PIP_PACKAGES ./install-conda-env.sh

Comment: We have found a bug in the Dataproc Agent that manifests itself very similarly to what you observe. Fix should be rolled out on next Friday.

Comment: Thank you  I also find out if some node disappear , it will cause chain reaction , job fail one by one .

Comment: howie@ Did you have a chance to use Dataproc recently? If so, may you confirm that this issue was resolved for you?

Comment: hi @IgorDvorzhak .I did not encounter this issue again. I think this issue was resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963668/some-yarn-worker-node-not-join-cluster-while-i-create-spark-cluster-on-datapro#comment91673474_51963668) that this issue is resolved and they didn't encounter it anymore.